# show parent class in R object

Tags: r, oop, inheritance, methods

I am using the default package `methods` in R so as to define my object oriented structure and I am trying to find out how to get a list of the classes that my object contains.

For example, let assume that my class def is the following:

```
Tr1 = setRefClass("Tr1", contains = "Tr2")
```

and I define an object `tr_ex = Tr1()`, how can I get which class `tr_ex` contains?..I can try `is(tr_ex,"Tr2")` but it's not really efficient.

Thanks!

Comment: `class(<object>)` returns the object's classes, but not the inheritance structure; however, you could infer this in most cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `getClassDef` on the class of your object. For example:

```
Tr2 <- setRefClass("Tr2", list(x="numeric"))
Tr1 <- setRefClass("Tr1", contains="Tr2")
tr_ex <- Tr1()
getClassDef(class(tr_ex))

Reference Class "Tr1":

Class fields:

Name:        x
Class: numeric

Class Methods: 
     "import", ".objectParent", "usingMethods", "show", "getClass", "untrace", 
     "export", ".objectPackage", "callSuper", "copy", "initFields", 
     "getRefClass", "trace", "field"

Reference Superclasses: 
     "Tr2", "envRefClass"
```

The specific slot you're after in this case is `@refSuperClasses`.